# How to express time intervals in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, time

I am trying to generate a sequence of dates separated at regular intervals, for example, starting from now, i want to produce the list:

```
[now, now + 10 minutes, now + 20 minutes, now + 30 minutes, ...]
```

My function will be based upon `iterate` and have two arguments, `start` and `interval` but which should be the types of those arguments? I have been wandering in the library and the wiki, without success. It seems that the recommended way to encode a time is using `UTCTime` from `Data.Time.Clock`, and the recommended way to encode a time difference is `NominalDiffTime`, but how do i generate a nominal time difference of one day? For example?

It seems that the `time-lens` package provides ways to do this, but as far as i know lenses are a way to improve expressiveness, i would be surprised if using lenses was the only way to solve this problem

Comment: This was confusing for me too.  Notice that `NominalDiffTime` is an instance of `Num`, which means it supports numeric literals. E.g. `1 :: NominalDiffTime`.  Not sure what that means, but it's probably enough to get you started.

Comment: Thanks. Correct if i am wrong: this is not visible in the documentation [generated by Haddock](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/time-1.2.0.3/docs/Data-Time-Clock.html#t:NominalDiffTime), so one should look at the source, right?

Comment: @danza Under the documentation for the type, it lists classes it is an instance of, including `Num`, so this information is indeed in the generated haddocks. The (human-written) documentation also says, "Conversion functions will treat it as seconds.".

Comment: Thanks! Now i understood better how to read the *instances* section!

Comment: Now i understand the source of my confusion about _instances_. Under type classes they will list implementing types, while under a concrete type they will list implemented type classes.

Comment: 1 :: NominalDiffTime is one second. However "succ" applied to either a UTCTime or a NominalDiffTime will increment it by 1 picosecond. In the past I've been caught out writing [t1 .. t2] and wondering why it was taking so long.

Comment: Not trying to be pedantic "time interval" is not what you're looking for in that argument. Using a geometric analogy: an interval is a line segment (and can be "closed" or "open" on either end). You're looking for something like a geometric vector (a "length of time", i.e. having only a magnitude and (incidentally or interestingly?) a direction (forward)) see also http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/torsors.html

Comment: thanks for the observation @jberryman. how would you call this? i guess that it could be called "time sampling"? once agreed i can rename ... keeping a reference to the old name for findability

Comment: @danza I'm not sure right off the top of my head (and it's probably fine to keep this name for searchability; probably other people will use the same terminology). And actually "time interval" does seem to be common usage, just scanning wikipedia, so I guess I retract my comment haha. It would be very nice if there was good terminology for talking about this sort of thing

Comment: @jberryman maybe "sampling sequence"? with reference to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sampling_(signal_processing)#Theory

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In ghci:

```
Data.Time> now <- getCurrentTime
Data.Time> let tenMinutes = 10*60
Data.Time> mapM_ print . take 10 . iterate (addUTCTime tenMinutes) $ now 
2015-06-27 20:14:21.445443 UTC
2015-06-27 20:24:21.445443 UTC
2015-06-27 20:34:21.445443 UTC
2015-06-27 20:44:21.445443 UTC
2015-06-27 20:54:21.445443 UTC
2015-06-27 21:04:21.445443 UTC
2015-06-27 21:14:21.445443 UTC
2015-06-27 21:24:21.445443 UTC
2015-06-27 21:34:21.445443 UTC
2015-06-27 21:44:21.445443 UTC
```

Note that `NominalDiffTime` (as used here) ignores leap seconds; that is, adding `60*60*24` will produce the same time with a different date, even if there are actually `60*60*24+1` seconds between those two UTC times. This is often (but not always) what you want. If you want to be leap-second aware, you can use `AbsoluteTime` and `DiffTime` instead of `UTCTime` and `NominalDiffTime`.

---

and of course your function could just be:

```
import Data.Time.Clock

timeSeq :: UTCTime -> NominalDiffTime -> [UTCTime]
timeSeq start interval = iterate (addUTCTime delta) start
```